# Extract data from txt file and get concise output

Tags: python, linux, awk

I need to pull some information from a .txt file and get a concise line of output
the output should look like:
`Display 1 - VMware SVGA 3D - 1600 x 900 x 32 bit @ 60 Hz - Primary Device`

The text file has the following information:

```
ws_diag 5.3.0 build-1427931
Device \\.\DISPLAY1
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Mode = 1555 x 794 x 32-bit @ 60Hz
   Bounds = 0,0  1555,794
   Flags = PRIMARY_DEVICE, ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP
Device \\.\DISPLAY2
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Flags = 0x00000000
Device \\.\DISPLAYV1
   Desc = "RDPDD Chained DD"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Device \\.\DISPLAYV2
   Desc = "RDP Encoder Mirror Driver"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Device \\.\DISPLAYV3
   Desc = "RDP Reflector Display Driver"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
monitor-info.txt (END)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import sys
file = open(monitor-info.txt[1])
while 1:
    line = file.readline()
    tpl = line.split(":")
    if tpl[0] == "Desc":
        var = tpl[0]
    if tpl[1] == "Mode":
        print var, tpl[1]
    if tpl[2] == "Flag":
        var = tpl[2]
    print var
       if not line:
        break
```

I've also tried `awk`:

```
awk -F: '/^Device/{v=$2}/^Desc/{print v $2}/^Mode/{print v$3}/^Flags/{print v$4}' output_file.txt
```

Comment: This is not a website where people write code for you. You should make an attempt and then you can ask more specific questions about that.

Comment: awk -F: '/^Device/{v=$2}/^Desc/{print v $2}/^Mode/{print v$3}/^Flags/{print v$4}' output_file.txt trying to use awk and print "Display 1 - VMware SVGA 3D - 1600 x 900 x 32 bit @ 60 Hz - Primary Device" from the txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, I think you were not far off with your first `awk` attempt. You simply set the field separator to `:` (`-F:`) when it should be `=`.

Maybe you could try :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="="; OFS=" - "; desc=""}function display(){print dev, desc, flags}/Device/{if(desc!="") display(); desc=""; flags=""; dev=$0; gsub("Dev.*PLAY", "Display ", dev)}/Desc/{desc=$2}/Flags/{flags=$2}END{display}'
```

What this does:

- at the beginning, sets field separator to `=` and output field separator to `-` (for formatting)
- defines a function `display` to print a line, because it will be called 2 times
- if line contains `Device`, print preceding device if any, store the id of the device and reset all other variables
- if line contains `Desc` (or `Mode`), store 2nd field in corresponding variable
- at end of file, print last device

And all that yields:

```
Display 1 - "VMware SVGA 3D" - PRIMARY_DEVICE, ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP
Display 2 - "VMware SVGA 3D" - 0x00000000
Display V1 - "RDP Encoder Mirror Driver" - MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Display V2 - "RDP Encoder Mirror Driver" - MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Display V3 - "RDP Encoder Mirror Driver" - MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
```

`awk` syntax is a bit cryptic, but very compact ...

Comment: it throws an error saying "awk: illegal statement
 input record number 19, file monitor_info.txt
 source line number 1"and does not seem to pull out the mode field... i tried with simple awk,it works but had trouble formatting '/Desc/
/Mode/
/Flag/' filename gives Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Mode = 1555 x 794 x 32-bit @ 60Hz
   Flags = PRIMARY_DEVICE, ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Flags = 0x00000000
   Desc = "RDPDD Chained DD"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE, any suggestions?

Comment: @user3731311 I cannot be surprised that the script does not pull the mode : I simply forgot it... I shall edit my post soon to fix it. For the error, can you tell me what is the 19th line of your input file (if it exists) ?

Comment: thanks guys finally made it work but it still sends out some error I did get the output in a different file **'BEGIN{FS="="; OFS=" - "; desc=""}function display(){print dev, desc,mode,flags}/Device/{if(desc!="") display(); desc=""; mode=""; flags=""; dev=$0; gsub("Dev.*PLAY", "Display ", dev)}/Desc/{desc=$2}/Mode/{mode=$2}/Flags/{flags=$2}END{display}' monitor_info.txt|cat > outputfile.txt**

Comment: this is my input file**ws_diag 5.3.0 build-1427931
Device \\.\DISPLAY1
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Mode = 1555 x 794 x 32-bit @ 60Hz
   Bounds = 0,0  1555,794
   Flags = PRIMARY_DEVICE, ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP
Device \\.\DISPLAY2
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Flags = 0x00000000
Device \\.\DISPLAYV1s
   Desc = "RDPDD Chained DD"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Device \\.\DISPLAYV2
   Desc = "RDP Encoder Mirror Driver"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Device \\.\DISPLAYV3
   Desc = "RDP Reflector Display Driver"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE**

Comment: @user3731311 I cannot reproduce any error when typing this data in a text file. I suppose there are control characters at end of file. Could you show me last lines of a dump (`od -xc`, `hexdump`, ...) of your file ?

Comment: **ws_diag 5.3.0 build-1427931
Device \\.\DISPLAY1
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Mode = 1555 x 794 x 32-bit @ 60Hz
   Bounds = 0,0  1555,794
   Flags = PRIMARY_DEVICE, ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP
Device \\.\DISPLAY2
   Desc = "VMware SVGA 3D"
   Flags = 0x00000000
Device \\.\DISPLAYV1s
   Desc = "RDPDD Chained DD"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Device \\.\DISPLAYV2
   Desc = "RDP Encoder Mirror Driver"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE
Device \\.\DISPLAYV3
   Desc = "RDP Reflector Display Driver"
   Flags = MIRRORING_DRIVER, TS_COMPATIBLE**

Comment: I'm sorry, what I need looks like that : `_COMPATIBLE\n` (with backslahed control chars) or `5f 43 4f 4d 50 54 41 54 49 42 4c 45 0a` (hexadecimal output). The problem is not with printable characters but with non printable ones.

Comment: i can not see that here, but I got the fix and its working when I output i to a file thank you Serge Ballesta. now I am stuck in a different problem would really appreciate your help thank you @Serge Ballesta

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -F'\n' -v RS='Device \\\\\\\\.\\\\' '
    NF > 2 { # ignore the extraneous very first line
      delete dict # delete dictionary from previous record
      dict["Device"] = $1 # store device name
      for (i=2;i<NF;++i) { # store other fields in dict.
        split($i, tkns, / = /) # split into field name (e.g., "Desc") and value 
          # clean up strings (remove leading spaces from field name, remove
          # double quotes from value, and store in dictionary.
        dict[gensub(/^ +/, "", "", tkns[1])] = gensub(/"/, "", "g", tkns[2])
      }
        # Output desired fields, using the dictionary.
      printf "%s - %s - %s - %s\n", dict["Device"], dict["Desc"], dict["Mode"], dict["Flags"]
    }
  ' file
```

Basic approach:

- Breaks the input into records, each comprising all lines related to a given display: `-v RS='Device \\\\\\\\.\\\\'` (note that each literal `\` in the input must be escaped with *3* `\`) . This sets special variable `RS`, the input record separator, which tells `awk` how to break the input into records based on the specified regular expression. (`$0` then refers to the entire current record being processed.)
- Each record is broken into fields by lines (`-F'\n'`) -`-F` sets special variable `FS`, the input field separator, which tells `awk` how to split each record into individual fields (`$1`, `$2`, ...)
- A dictionary of field values is then built up, so that values can be referred to by field name, e.g. `dict["Desc"]` - see the comments in the source code.
- Finally, a single `printf` statement synthesizes the desired output string from the field values of interest.

Note: The following GNU-specific, non-POSIX features were used:

- a `RS` value that is not just a single character
- The `gensub()` function for flexible, regex-based string replacement (more flexible than the POSIX `sub`/`gsub` functions)
- Using the `delete` statement to delete an *entire* array.

Comment: The multi-line record is a very nice trick ! BTW, thank you for improving my answer.